# How To Recolor An Already Existing Polygon In Leaflet With Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

Currently I have shapefiles for all counties for all 50 states. And I am coloring them based on some outcome variable chosen by the user (e.g. unemployment, poverty rate, etc.)

Using leafletProxy() I can update the color however this necessitates a redrawing of the polygons even though it is the same polygons being drawn over and over again! I just want to change the color.

Normally, this wouldn't be an issue, but because it is a relatively large collection of shapefiles it can take a bit before the map updates.

I was wondering if anyone out there knew of a way to edit an already existing polygons without having to redraw them. I am not so well versed in Javascript (hence why I am using leaflet for R) so if I could figure out how to do it that way I would have already.

I've also already reduced the size of the shape files down as much as possible.

It's also possible something like this already exists in leaflet.extras? I haven't been able to find anything in leaflet.extras but perhaps somebody knows something?